# Sony Walkman NWZ-B173F 12.04 support

Tags: 12.04, mount, sony, mp3-player

I bought this groovy little device for my daughters only to discover they didn't play nice with Ubuntu.  My main desktop runs 12.04 64bit.  My secondary desktop runs 13.04.
Didn't get recognised on either.

It appeared in dmesg and syslog and the "disks utility" app, but the filesystem type was not recognised which seems to be why it didn't mount.

After much searching etc, I've figured out how to mount it.  It's a vfat partition.

`mount /dev/sdg /media/walkman`

(I manually created the walkman directory)

Took me awhile to figure this out as I normally mount scsi drives as something like sdg1 or sda2 (depending on the partition)

So I've got around the initial problem of not being able to transfer music across, but I'm a little puzzled as to why this would not auto-mount.

Any thoughts out there?

Answer (score -1):

I found this article helpful for figuring out how to mount it. It walks you step by step through the process of manually making the directory. Also, I used Disk Utility to identify what the sony drive was called on by Ubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

Answer (score -1):

I have a sony walkman nwz-b152 here and I started running into problems after messing up with the `ehci/xhci` [sleep issues](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1460790) (1) on my laptop, it auto mounts but the file transfers always fail. Before Karmic, you used to be able to `rmmod` the `ehci` modules but 13.04 has brought upgrades and now it's hardcoded in the kernel so you need to [do some more keyboard gym if you want to unload the USB 2.0](http://www.geekdevs.com/2010/04/solved-unable-to-enumerate-usb-device-disabling-ehci_hcd/) (2).

I'm not sure if you are experiencing problems because of that as well, however, you could simply fix your automount by supplementing `/etc/fstab` with your mp3 payer UUID and make a system-wide automount. The details to modify `/etc/fstab` are found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) under the section *Systemwide mounts*.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend editing this to include instructions on exactly how to edit `/etc/fstab` as you're suggesting. Also, *if* any part of this is intended as a *question* (or other request for help) rather than an *answer*, I recommend posting that as a new question instead. *Ask Ubuntu is a question-answer site and [works *very differently* from a forum](http://askubuntu.com/about).)

Comment: Recommandation acknoeldged, will do this asap.

Answer (score -1):

You could format drive in fat32, after that it would appear as normal flash drive on your pc. Tried this with my player, no problems so far.

Comment: note with many devices this might break them, as they may have needed software on the drive, or can only read vfat. It will also likely do in any warranty etc